# Returning Subset Of List in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I want to test a function that returns a list of complex type. So I need moq to simulate this function. The function is
*IEnumerable (Worker> ReadWorkerList(AcademicTitle title);*

During the setup section of the moq, I have created a artifical *Worker* list
(code-1) and I cannot instruct moq to return the subset of worker list which satisfies the AcademicTitle criteria in the parameter. (code-2)

I have read the urls below and I cannot find solution.

[Return Subset of List that Matches Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101426/return-subset-of-list-that-matches-condition)
[Moq Return using Where()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558597/moq-return-using-where)
[Mock object returning a list of mocks with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139908/mock-object-returning-a-list-of-mocks-with-moq)
[MOQ C# QUERIES It.IsAny returning a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767162/moq-c-sharp-queries-it-isany-returning-a-list)
[Overloaded return values in MOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715191/overloaded-return-values-in-moq)

Definition of Worker:

```
public class Worker
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }       

    public AcademicTitle Title { get; set; }

}

//Moq implementation: (code-1)
internal static Mock<IWorkerRepository> GetIWorkerRepository ()
{

   try
   {
      if (_workerRepositoryMock == null)
      {
         //artifical worker list
         List<Worker> workerList = new List<Worker>() {
             new Worker("name1", "surname1",AcademicTitle.Doctor),
             new Worker("name2", "surname2",AcademicTitle.Empty),
             new Worker("name3", "surname3",AcademicTitle.AssociateProfessor),
             new Worker("name4", "surname4",AcademicTitle.Professor),


         };

         _workerRepositoryMock = new Mock<IWorkerRepository>();
         _workerRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.ReadWorkerList(It.IsAny<AcademicTitle>())).Returns(new List<Worker>());

         //Code -2

         _workerRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.ReadWorkerList(It.Is<AcademicTitle>(v=>v != AcademicTitle.Empty))).Returns(workerList.Where(p=>p.Title  == v));


        }
           return _workerRepositoryMock;

    }catch (Exception hata)
    {
         throw hata;
    }

}
```

Expected result is, when I call *ReadWorkerList* function with a specific AcademicTitle parameter, let's say *Professor*, only a list that contains *name4* should be returned.

Comment: Can you share the signature of `ReadWorkerList` method?

Comment: *IEnumerable (Worker> ReadWorkerList(AcademicTitle title);*

Excuse me, some characters hasn't printed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible, try this:

```
_workerRepositoryMock
    .Setup(m => m.ReadWorkerList(It.Is<AcademicTitle>(v => v != AcademicTitle.Empty)))
    .Returns((AcademicTitle v) => workerList.Where(p => p.Title == v));
```

Comment: There are three functions that sharing the same name with the function in *ReadWorkerList* and the error is "no overload for method 'IsAny' takes 1 argument"

Comment: It should be

          _workerRepositoryMock.Setup(m => ReadWorkerList(It.Is<AcademicTitle>(v => v != AcademicTitle.Empty)))    .Returns((AcademicTitle v) => calisanListe.Where(p => p.Title == v)); 
Please note that It.Is used instead of It.IsAny.